# Does contract address support uppercase?

Tags: addresses

Does it support uppercase in web3.js? I write and deploy a test contract on rinkeby `0x7b84de0c31d308b42427d562306526e3eb95c825`  if I change it to uppercase it return error `Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0x7b84de0c31d308b42427d562306526e3eb95c825 is not a contract address`.

So I think contract address not support uppercase now.

I search like 'eth contract address uppercase' and read the wiki on github, but still not find any thing;

Can anyone give me an offical ansower ? and If it will support uppercase in future.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen sorry , It support uppercase, It's some problem of my geth node. change every char to uppercase like '0X7B84DE0C31D308B42427D562306526E3EB95C825' work well ,but If just change some it return `Provided address "0x7B84de0c31d308b42427d562306526e3eb95c825" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.`

Comment: Read the duplicate post which I linked. It tells you that it's about the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , it's just because my new node still not finish sync. Contract address support uppercase like user address.